# Getting error in Google contacts API

Tags: google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api, google-apps-for-education

I am working on Google Apps for Education to integrate with my .net application.I want to integrate google contacts to my application.For that i am using below code

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.Contacts;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public static DataSet GetGmailContacts(string App_Name, string Uname, string UPassword)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataColumn C2 = new DataColumn();

        C2.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

        C2.ColumnName = "EmailID";

        dt.Columns.Add(C2);



        RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(App_Name, Uname, UPassword);

        rs.AutoPaging = true;

        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);

        Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();

        foreach (Contact t in f.Entries)
        {

            foreach (EMail email in t.Emails)
            {

                DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();

                dr1["EmailID"] = email.Address.ToString();

                dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

            }

        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        return ds;

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       DataSet ds = GetGmailContacts("MyNetwork Web Application!", txtgmailusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);

        gvmails.DataSource = ds;

        gvmails.DataBind();
    }
}
```

When i execute the above code i am getting below error.

"**Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404**"

How to solve this error.please help me on this...

Comment: There is something wrong with your authentication you haven't posted that code.   you need to use Oauth2.

Comment: Sorry DalmTo.Now i edited my post with all code in cs file.please help me if i miss any thing in code.

Comment: you need to use Oauth2 login and password isn't going to work anymore.   https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs?r=1159

Comment: Thanks DalmTo for your quick response. I am taking this code from below sites.
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/04/import-contacts-from-gmail.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/552508/ASP-NET-Import-Gmail-Contacts

How their code working fine but same code in my page not working.What is the solution for this

Comment: that article was published in Apr 2, 2010.   May 2015 Google shut down the client login servers they no longer allow you to authenticate using a login and password.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5101

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.But u am very new to this Google contacts API.So please refer me some code which is already implemented this functionality.

Comment: I did 3 comments ago https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs?r=1159